# Combine records from 2 tables

Tags: sql-server, join

i have the following situation:

```
Table1
Zone   Customer  Brand   Sales2016
ZoneA  X         A       100
ZoneB  Y         C       200
ZoneA  X         B       300


Table2
Zone   Customer  Brand  Sales2017  Lastmonthsales
ZoneA  X         A      400        50
ZoneB  Y         B      500        0
```

I want to combine all records from theose 2 tables in one query to look like

```
Zone   Customer  Brand  Sales2016  Sales2017  Lastmonthsales
ZoneA  X         A      100        400        50
ZoneA  X         B      300        0          0
ZoneB  Y         B      0          500        0 
ZoneB  Y         C      200        0          0
```

I did:

```
SELECT t1.zone, t1.customer, t1.brand, t1.sales2016, t2.sales2017, t2.lastmonthsales 
from table1 t1 
full outer join table2 t2 on t1.zone = t2.zone
```

but did not succeed. The values duplicated.
[image]

Comment: May be you should reconsider your join condition then.

Comment: How ? I want all the info from both tables, and combine them if same zone & customer & brand found

Comment: Could you please post your tables and data as DDL (`CREATE TABLE blah (...);`) and DML (`INSERT INTO blah VALUES (...);`). Help us to help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your sample data, this returns the result you are looking for:

```
Declare @Table1 table(Zone varchar(10), Customer char(1), Brand char(1), Sales2016 int)
insert into @Table1(Zone,Customer,Brand,Sales2016)
values('ZoneA','X','A',100),('ZoneB','Y','C',200),('ZoneA','X','B',300)

Declare @Table2 table (Zone varchar(10), Customer char(1), Brand char(1), Sales2017 int, LastMonthSales int)
insert into @Table2(Zone,Customer,Brand,Sales2017,LastMonthSales)
values('ZoneA','X','A',400,50),('ZoneB','Y','B',500,0)
;
With ResultSet as
(
        SELECT CASE WHEN t1.zone IS NULL THEN t2.zone ELSE t1.zone  END AS zone
            ,CASE WHEN t1.customer IS NULL THEN t2.customer ELSE t1.Customer END AS customer
            ,CASE WHEN t1.brand IS NULL THEN t2.brand ELSE t1.brand END AS brand
            ,CASE WHEN t1.sales2016 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE t1.Sales2016 END AS Sales2016
            ,CASE WHEN t2.sales2017 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE t2.Sales2017 END AS Sales2017
            ,CASE WHEN t2.lastmonthsales IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE t2.LastMonthSales END AS LastMonthSales
        FROM @Table1 t1
        FULL OUTER JOIN @Table2 t2 ON t1.zone = t2.zone
            AND t1.Customer = t2.Customer
            AND t1.Brand = t2.brand
        )

SELECT * FROM ResultSet
ORDER BY zone,customer,brand
```

---

```
| zone  | customer | brand | Sales2016 | Sales2017 | LastMonthSales |
|-------|----------|-------|-----------|-----------|----------------|
| ZoneA | X        | A     | 100       | 400       | 50             |
| ZoneA | X        | B     | 300       | 0         | 0              |
| ZoneB | Y        | B     | 0         | 500       | 0              |
| ZoneB | Y        | C     | 200       | 0         | 0              |
```

Answer (score 1):

Same idea as Scott's solution but using COALESCE instead of CASE:

```
select coalesce(t1.zone, t2.zone)
     , coalesce(t1.customer, t2.customer)
     , coalesce(t1.brand, t2.brand)
     , coalesce(t1.Sales2016,0)
     , coalesce(t2.Sales2017,0)
     , coalesce(t2.Lastmonthsales,0) 
from table1 t1 
full join table2 t2 
    on t1.zone = t2.zone 
   and t1.customer = t2.customer 
   and t1.brand = t2.brand;
```